# Handling case weight in the Random Forest packages in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I checked both the `randomForest` and the `rfsrc` packages in R, but couldn't find an easy way to apply observation/case weight when training the random forest model. Is there any way to do this?

As an alternative I thought about replicating my observations (e.g. replicate once if the observation has a weight of 2), but think this would be inefficient and difficult for non-integer case weight.

Comment: In `randomForest` function there is only one option to weight classes - `classwt`. It can be applied only for classification tasks. If you need to weight individual cases probably there is no other option than replicate them.

Comment: replicate if you have a lot of data then you could replicate in probabilistic manner

Answer (score 1):

You could use the tree package which allows you to weight individual observations. This would of course only give you a single tree, so you would have to make the random forest yourself.

It might be a little more work, but it's probably a better solution than replicating observations.